# Had signed up for Teams Beta, can't see Create Team button

Tags: support, old-teams

As title already explains, so I had signed up for Teams Beta few months back, but I can't see "Create Team" button anywhere.

I did researched a bit on how to create teams but that button is not showing up for me.

Am I missing something or we cannot create teams anymore?

Comment: Have you received a private beta invite? Team creation is limited only to those in the private beta currently.

Comment: @Hynes Checked my inbox, I didn't got any invite, but it's weird because I did signed up for one.

Comment: Why is that weird? You applied for consideration, but not everyone gets in.

Comment: @jonrsharpe didn't knew it was selective.